# Proxy is working but not url in .env file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, mern

when i use proxy my app it is running fine. Then I added a `.env` file outside the src folder and added

```
REACT_APP_API_URL = "http://localhost:4000"
```

and accessed It like

```
//login action
export const login =(email,password) => async (dispatch)=>{
    try{
        dispatch({ type:LOGIN_REQUEST })

        const config = { headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json" } };

        const { data } =  await axios.post(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/v1/login`,
            {email, password},
            config
        )

        dispatch({type:LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload:data.user})
    }
    catch(error){
        dispatch({ type:LOGIN_FAIL, payload:error.response.data.message });
    }
}

//Load  User
export const LoadUser =() => async (dispatch)=>{
    try{
        dispatch({ type:LOAD_USER_REQUEST })


        const { data } =  await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/v1/me`)
      alert(data.user)
        dispatch({type:LOAD_USER_SUCCESS, payload:data.user})
    }
    catch(error){
        dispatch({ type:LOAD_USER_FAIL, payload:error.response.data.message });
    }
}
```

Login Is working fine but User is not loaded in the state after using

```
REACT_APP_API_URL
```

but when I use `proxy` in `package.json` it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried a  console.log() inspecting the api url var?

Comment: yes instead of alert I used  console but it's not getting dispatched after using process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL

Comment: How is the `.env` file loaded?

Comment: outside the src folder I have created a `.env` file with the `REACT_APP_API_URL` then trying to access it through  `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL` in the actions as I am using redux.

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet you shared, you aren't loading the `.env` file at all:

```js
require('dotenv').config('../.env');
```

Comment: this is a react app do we need to load env file ? where I have to load it ?

Comment: @AnjaliTejasvi somewhere at the beginning of the app, before you try using any variable defined there

Comment: no , It's not there

Comment: @AnjaliTejasvi right, you need to add it

Comment: where It's a react application. you mean I have to add `require('dotenv').config('../.env');
` int the beginning? env file is in root directory

Comment: my question is it's working for some routes and not working for some